# Align a SceneKit Plane to Face of cube

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

I have created a scnbox in SceneKit and am trying to add a circular plane on the face that is touched by the user.

I can add the SCNPlane as a child node at the touch point using the hittest but I’m struggling to orient the plane to the face that was touched.

The localnormal vector provided as part of hit test seems to be what I need but I’m nit sure how to use it. Normally I would orient using the EulerAngles property but localnormal looks to be a vector. I tried Look(at:) which takes a vector3 but that didn’t seem to work. 
Any suggestions would be gratefully received. Code sample below which is taken from touchesBegan. "result" is the SCNHitTestResult:

```
//Draw circular plane, double sided
let circle =  SCNPlane(width: 0.1, height: 0.1) //SCNSphere(radius: 0.1)
circle.cornerRadius = 0.5
circle.materials.first?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.black
circle.materials.first?.isDoubleSided = true
let circleNode = SCNNode(geometry: circle)

//Set position to hit test
circleNode.position = result.localCoordinates
let lookAtPoint = SCNVector3(result.localNormal.x * 100, result.localNormal.y * 100, result.localNormal.z * 100)

//Align to far point on normal
circleNode.look(at: lookAtPoint)
//Add to touched node
result.node.addChildNode(circleNode)
```

Comment: please add some code so other can understand what you done till now

Comment: I have added code sample. As an update I got close to what I need by multiplying the localNormal vector to give long distance and using the look(at:) function. I would have thought there would be a cleaner way of doing this but can't see how...